# Calculus - differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the differential equation below:

$$\sqrt{x}\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{y+\sqrt{x}}$$ for $x>0$.

The correct answer is $C=e^{-y} + 2e^{\sqrt{x}}$, but I don't know how to work the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We can rewrite the DE as:

$$e^{-y}y'=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Do you see how to proceed by integrating?

Comment: Yes, I got it from here. Thanks.